# LabelMe XML to CSV

Tags: python, csv, image-processing, object-detection

I have the annotated xml files generated from LabelMe tool.
I have to convert it into csv file.

```
<annotation><filename>image10.jpg</filename><folder>users/mayurakewar//card</folder><source><submittedBy>Mayur Akewar</submittedBy></source><imagesize><nrows>480</nrows><ncols>640</ncols></imagesize><object><name>id card</name><deleted>0</deleted><verified>0</verified><occluded>yes</occluded><attributes/><parts></parts><date>18-Oct-2018 18:01:12</date><id>0</id><polygon><username>anonymous</username><pt><x>141</x><y>167</y></pt><pt><x>228</x><y>161</y></pt><pt><x>237</x><y>307</y></pt><pt><x>149</x><y>308</y></pt></polygon></object></annotation>
```

The columns of CSV must be size of image, label, x and y object detection boundary.

---

Below is a 'pretty print' of the same data:

```
<annotation>
    <filename>image10.jpg</filename>
    <folder>users/mayurakewar//card</folder>
    <source>
        <submittedBy>Mayur Akewar</submittedBy>
    </source>
    <imagesize>
        <nrows>480</nrows>
        <ncols>640</ncols>
    </imagesize>
    <object>
        <name>id card</name>
        <deleted>0</deleted>
        <verified>0</verified>
        <occluded>yes</occluded>
        <attributes/>
        <parts></parts>
        <date>18-Oct-2018 18:01:12</date>
        <id>0</id>
        <polygon>
            <username>anonymous</username>
            <pt>
                <x>141</x>
                <y>167</y>
            </pt>
            <pt>
                <x>228</x>
                <y>161</y>
            </pt>
            <pt>
                <x>237</x>
                <y>307</y>
            </pt>
            <pt>
                <x>149</x>
                <y>308</y>
            </pt>
        </polygon>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a nested data structure. I'm not sure if you can convert it into a CSV. First you need to convert it into a flat structure first and then sort it by its columns.

By the way, I'm not quite sure if this question is appropriate in StackOverflow.